# Approximation property confusion

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

I am a bit confused about this:

> If $A$ is an algebra of sets then for any $B \in \sigma(A)$ there exists a sequence of $B_n \in A$ such that $P(B \Delta B_n) \to 0$

$A \Delta B $ is denoting the symmetric difference- $ (A \backslash B) \cup (B \backslash A) $

The proof begins with $\mathcal D = \{ B\in \sigma(A):\exists B_n\in A, P(B \Delta B_n)\to 0 \}$

So this is the set of all elements in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $A$ with that property.

The proof shows that $\mathcal D$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and, since we have $A \subset \mathcal D,$ $ \sigma(A)\subset \mathcal D$, completing the proof.

Before getting to the main part of this proof, I cannot understand the joint significance of the above three things:

1. Why the fact that $\mathcal D $ is a $\sigma$-algebra is something which is important
2. How $A \subset \mathcal D$
3. How (2) $\Rightarrow \sigma(A) \subset \mathcal D$

I get that if $\sigma(A) \subset \mathcal D$ then it proves $\forall B\in \sigma(A)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1.: You want to prove that a property holds for every element of $\sigma(A)$, that is, for every element of *the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains* $A$. So the set of elements of $\sigma(A)$ that have that property should itself be a $\sigma$-algebra.

Ad 2.: Choose $B_n = B$ for all $n$ if $B\in A$ to see that every element of $A$ has the desired property.

Ad 3.: $\mathcal{D}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $A$ by 1. and 2. Therefore it contains *the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains* $A$.